# Concurrency in Linux: Alternate access of two threads in critical zone

Tags: linux, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I'm new with the concepts of concurrency and threads in Linux and I tried to solve a relative simple problem. I create two threads which run the same function which increment a global variable. What I really want from my program is to increment that variable alternatively, namely ,say in each step the thread that increment that variable prints to the screen a message , so the expected output should look like:

```
Thread 1 is incrementing variable count... count = 1
Thread 2 is incrementing variable count... count = 2
Thread 1 is incrementing variable count... count = 3
Thread 2 is incrementing variable count... count = 4
```

and so on.

I tried an implementation with a semaphore which ensures mutual exclusion, but nonetheless the result resembles this:

```
Thread 2 is incrementing variable count... count = 1
Thread 2 is incrementing variable count... count = 2
Thread 2 is incrementing variable count... count = 3
Thread 2 is incrementing variable count... count = 4
Thread 2 is incrementing variable count... count = 5
Thread 1 is incrementing variable count... count = 6
Thread 1 is incrementing variable count... count = 7
Thread 1 is incrementing variable count... count = 8
Thread 1 is incrementing variable count... count = 9
Thread 1 is incrementing variable count... count = 10
```

My code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int count = 0;
sem_t mutex;

void function1(void *arg)
{
        int i = 0;
        int *a = (int*) arg;

        while (i < 10)
        {
           sem_wait(&mutex);
           count++;
           i++;
           printf("From the function : %d count is %d\n",*a,count);
           sem_post(&mutex);
        }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,(void *)function1,&a);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,(void *)function1,&b);

    sem_init(&mutex,0,1);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);
    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    sem_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

My big question is now , how do I achieve this alternation between threads? I got mutual exclusion , but the alternation is still missing. Maybe I lack a good insight of semaphores usage, but I would be very grateful if someone would explain that to me. (I have read several courses on this topic ,namely,Linux semaphores,concurrency and threads, but the information there wasn't satisfactory enough)

Answer (score 0):

Mutex locks don't guarantee any fairness. This means that if thread 1 releases it and then attempts to get it again, there is no guarantee that it won't - it's just guarantees that no two pieces of code can be running in that block at the same time.

**EDIT:** *Removed previous C-style solution because it was probably incorrect. The question asks for a synchronization solution.*

If you really want to do this correctly you would use something called a monitor and a guard (or condition variable). I'm not too familiar with C and pThreads so you would need to take a look how to do it with that, but in Java it would look something like:

```java
  public class IncrementableInteger {
    public int value;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.valueOf(value);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void testThreadAlternating() throws InterruptedException {
    IncrementableInteger i = new IncrementableInteger();

    Monitor m = new Monitor();
    Monitor.Guard modIsZeroGuard = new Monitor.Guard(m) {
      @Override public boolean isSatisfied() {
        return i.value % 2 == 0;
      }
    };

    Monitor.Guard modIsOneGuard = new Monitor.Guard(m) {
      @Override public boolean isSatisfied() {
        return i.value % 2 == 1;
      }
    };

    Thread one = new Thread(() -> {
      while (true) {
        m.enterWhenUninterruptibly(modIsZeroGuard);
        try {
          if (i.value >= 10) return;
          i.value++;
          System.out.println("Thread 1 inc: " + String.valueOf(i));
        } finally {
          m.leave();
        }
      }
    });

    Thread two = new Thread(() -> {
      while (true) {
        m.enterWhenUninterruptibly(modIsOneGuard);
        try {
          if (i.value >= 10) return;
          i.value++;
          System.out.println("Thread 2 inc: " + String.valueOf(i));
        } finally {
          m.leave();
        }
      }
    });

    one.start();
    two.start();

    one.join();
    two.join();
  }
```

Comment: I have written the code in my IDE, it actually blocks after the first print

Comment: So I don't think it's actually blocking, likely what happens is that the first thread just continually gets the mutex. So if you were to add a print outside of the if statement saying "Thread *a is running" you should see it continuously print that out. Is that what happens?